# How can I transfer the origin position to another object?

Tags: geometry-nodes, origin

I intend to create a drawer and a set of handles. My idea was to capture the origin of the drawer and transfer it to the handles.

The problem is that I was only able to transfer the position of vertex/ edges/ faces. I could not find a way to capture the origin of the geometry to transfer it.

Does someone know how to capture the position by the origin?

[image: node example]

EDIT:

My idea was to create **OBJECT A**, then create and bind **OBJECT B** to the same origin of **OBJECT A**. So, if I do any kind of operation of translation/ rotation on **OBJECT A** it would automatically reflect in **OBJECT B**.

A different way of describing this: *I want to do something similar to parenting **OBJECT B** to **OBJECT A***.

I created this to exemplify what I have in mind.

[image: node example2]

EDIT2:
**quellenform's suggestion worked**. I only did a small tweak to add the rotation control.

[image: final node]

Comment: In local space the origin denotes the coordinates (0, 0, 0), in the world space it's the location of the object. You can't alter the location of the object from within the geonodes, unless you're interested in controlling the effect somehow in geonodes, but using external tools like drivers...

Comment: tbh you should not describe what you technically want to do, but what control/animation you want to have. By that we can help you much better and often there comes up a solution you haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node `Set Position` always refers to the individual points of a mesh. However, you need exactly one point here, namely the origin point of the geometry.

The easiest way in your case might be a detour via instances, because these can be easily transformed and the transformation can be easily transferred.

You could solve this like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks! This set up did what I was intending. I only had to add a note to transfer the rotation also.